# how do I make xdotool press ctrl c and ctrl v

Tags: xdotool

xdotool key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work (I am on rpi3b+)

Answer (score 8):

```
xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c
xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+v
```

Comment: `getactivewindow` isn't actually required, the important part is the non-capitalised "`c`".

Comment: Danke Schön!  **0:-)**